# Microsoft Graph API/ EWS not return order of child folders list as Outlook app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I want to get child folders of Inbox which have same order as Outlook app.

Now Graph API and EWS return same result but not same order as Outlook app.

Does Graph API or EWS support that?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-childfolders

Comment: By default the sort order for folder is alphabetical A-Z, if the user has placed a custom view on the folder in Outlook then you would need to read that from the Custom view configuration object. Generally alphabetically A-Z would be acceptable for any user in a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 0):

I used both the APIs. but none of them return the way as you're expecting above. Rather, i have a suggestion here, get the folder values, tabulate or implement you custom logic and show the folders as you wish. Instead of these two, you may want to check with legacy MAPI (or play with MFCMAPI utility) to see if it works as you look.